# search a range of numbers in certain column and hide rows that aren't in the range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

i want to search a certain column of a table for a range of numbers without datatable plugin and using jquery or javascript.
a textbox for minimum value and a textbox for maximum value.

i have a simple search for certain column but i don't know how to make it search for a range.

javascript :

```
function SFNAAB_Code() {

    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("SFNAAB_CodeInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="SFNAAB_CodeInput" onkeyup="SFNAAB_Code()" 
placeholder="Search By NAAB Code...">

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAAB_CODE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ICC)
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAAB_CODE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ICC)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I think you would have to make a td for each column to search and then OR each condition in your if check

Comment: Are you saying you want `td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1` to be a range check rather than an existence check?

Comment: @Taplar yes ! , and how do i change it to have two textbox for minimum and maximum value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it using Range search of datatables plugin with these options :

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        info: false
    });
```

and also removed the f from sDOM.
heres the code :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0;

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false
});

$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
} );
```

[datatables Custom filtering - range search](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)